# My Latin-1 coding tag is not working in python 3.4 but works fine in python 2.7

Tags: python, latin1

I am trying to make a web page using Bottle.py, Mongodb and Python.

I had this tag on top of my python 2.7 code:

```
# #-- coding: latin1 --
```

I use the coding for getting bottle requests such as:

```
CheckboxTr= bottle.request.forms.getlist("CheckboxTr")
tags = bottle.request.forms.get("tags")
```

I also have `meta charset="•ISO-8859-1"` on top of each web page, and everything worked fine. However, when I tried to migrate to python 3.4 I get no error message, but my coding seems to be UTF-8 instead of Latin-1 (accent characters won't print as they should).

I hope you can help me. I am missing something for the migration to work, maybe they updated the coding name or something, but I have been reading python 3.4 coding and can´t find my error.

This is the code:

```
@bottle.post('/newpost')
def post_newpost():
    title = bottle.request.forms.get("subject")
    post = bottle.request.forms.get("body")
    beneficios = bottle.request.forms.get("beneficios")
    CheckboxTramite= bottle.request.forms.getlist("CheckboxTramite")
    cookie = bottle.request.get_cookie("session")
    username = sessions.get_username(cookie)
    dependencia = sessions.get_dependencia(cookie)

return bottle.template("newpost_template1", dict(subject="", body = "", errors="", tags="", username=username, dependencia=dependencia, beneficios="", CheckboxTramite=[],))
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the [wrong `coding` syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#source-code-encoding). You're missing the stars. It only "worked" in Python 2 because the default encoding was ASCII instead of UTF-8.

Comment: I have tried: # -*- coding: latin-1 -*-, # -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
, # coding=latin-1

Comment: @HenryKeiter: no, that's fine; it'll match the regular expression used (see [PEP 263](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)). But without source code there is little we can do but speculate here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ahh, right you are. Still looks weird.

Comment: @HenryKeiter: No; the regular expression is `coding[:=]\s*([-\w.]+)"`. So `coding` followed by a colon or equals sign, followed by optional whitespace and the actual codec name. It has to be a comment and the first or second line, any other characters on that line are sugar coating for whatever editor you want to recognise the comment too.

Comment: When you say "on top" was it the very first line of the file?

Comment: Can you show the `repr` of one of the strings that appears to be incorrect? It may provide a vital hint.

Comment: Yes, on top is the first line of the code. And before I migrated to python 3.4 one of the strings I wanted to show was: "acción", now it is"acciÃ³n".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the encoding for Bottle's output would change, since it's documented as being `utf-8` by default. However [the documentation](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#generating-content) states that you can change it by setting the `Response.charset` attribute. Have a look at the example under "Changing the Default Encoding".

This has nothing to do with the encoding of your Python source files, as some of the comments to the question are hinting.